# Как надпись на input заменить на иконку fontawesome?

Tags: html, css, form, input

Есть сайт на wordpress и форма контактов contact form 7. Хочу вместо надписи на кнопке *отправить* поместить иконку `fa-phone-square` - как это можно сделать? `Input` с `:before` не работает..

```html
<form action="/#wpcf7-f18804-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="18804">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.3.1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f18804-o1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="3f41b2afdb">
  </div>
  <p>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="ВАШЕ ИМЯ"></span> 
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-126"><input type="tel" name="tel-126" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА"></span> 
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
    <img class="ajax-loader" alt="Отправка..." style="visibility: hidden;">
  </p>
  <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: А вы кстати можете убрать <div style="display: none;">, так как ваши <input type="hidden" и так невидимые.

Comment: @Lesperanza их автоматом плагин подгружает. `display: none;` наверное, чтобы при загрузке страницы вдруг `input` сразу не появились, а потом спрятались я так думаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте `button type="submit"`

Пример

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
  <i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: да одновременно пришли к одному ответу)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден:
нужно

```
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
```

заменить на это

```
<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
    <i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>
</button>
```